# Is there other way to include a php file on a remote server? Other than <?php include(); ?>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, scripting

I've built a php script that extracts info from a MySQL database, and I want to include that script (it's content that is extracted from the db) on some remote servers. Those clients have websites built with joomla/wordpress and using a simple php include(); within an article/post would not work. I need something that's easy to use, a "paste-n-go" solution if you like.

Anyway, I don't care about the scripting language, as long as there is a way to embed that page.

Someone told me that it can be done via javascript with a file that will locally call that page, and then another bit of code that will remotely call that script. Sorry if this is confusing...

Comment: you can't include a a php file from a remote server in php

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu: Actually you can, but what would happen will possibly be unexpected.

Comment: nice to hear that you dont care and that you just want to use a paste and go solution, no what have you tried, no actual knowledge whatsoever

Comment: Actually you can, try `include('http://someserver.com/somefile.php');`. Dangerous as hell!

Comment: he does not want to include, he just want to display contents

Answer (score 2):

See this: http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

Comment: mightyuhu is right. using <?php include("path/to/remotefile.php"); ?> is the easy way to do it. The clients don't have any coding knowledge, that's why I've asked for a "paste-n-go" type of script. Not the actual script... some pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1):

for the php side of things...

**include/require/include_once...**

```
include 'http://www.example.com/yourfile.php';
```

actually should work, unless your service provider has some brain cells invested into security.

**file_get_contents**

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/yourfile.php');
echo $homepage;
```

**fopen**

```
$file = fopen ("http://www.example.com/yourfile.php", "r");
if (!$file) {
    echo "<p>Unable to open remote file.\n";
    exit;
}
while (!feof ($file)) {
    $line = fgets ($file, 1024);
    echo $line;
}
fclose($file);
```

**curl**

```
$url  = 'http://www.example.com/yourfile.php';
$path = '/yourfile.php';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $data; 
curl_close($ch);
```

**wget/curl call over the shell...**

```
exec('wget http://example.com/yourpage.php', $array);

echo implode('<br />', $array);
```

there are countless ways.. - pretty sure i forgot some -  to do this, by javascript (ajax/xhr), by html5, by iframes...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like JSONP as pure jevascript solution. Or define a rpc interface with for example xml-rpc, json-rpc, soap etc. and fetch the data via a php script as you described. Using only include for this is not a good idea since the function isn't made for this.

I like to use a simple json_encode on the server side and fetch da data via curl and decode them back via json_decode because most of the time a don't need a full rpc implementation.

You can write a class for your clients which they can easily use and you can also get shure they get the informations the right way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need an AJAX request to pull the result set from a PHP script.  Since the PHP script needs to look at a 'foreign' url, have a look at the PHP documentation for [curl](http://ca.php.net/curl).

For WordPress clients, your paste-n-go functionality might be in the form of a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). You'd write a WordPress plug-in to encapsulate all the above.

I'm assuming Joomla would allow something similar.

Comment: I guess you're on the right track. I have the script at the same location as the db, so the whole thing is local. The only problem is that I don't know how to get the content of that script to display remotely.

Comment: @PopaAndrei: your WP plugin would use curl() to call your script.  In other words, there is a content generating script which lives on the same server as your db, and there is a content pulling script which is remote from your server.